# Relevant subtree and relevant leaf in Machine Learning Decision Trees

Tags: machine-learning, decision-problem

I'm currently studying Decision Trees and the definition of a decision tree in our course is somewhat obscure for me. Nowhere in other online definitions of decision trees do I find something about relevant subtrees and relevant leafs...

The course is based on the book Machine Learning from Tom Mitchell, so I'll have a look in that book for more information.

I wanted to know if someone can explain to me in English a relevant subtree and a relevant leaf...

If the question is too vague or abstract, I'll first read the chapter in Tom Mitchell's book and then come back to this forum.